# Can't use use the update_request_callback to send Provisioning request

Tags: cobalt, eme

I encountered the same problem, the Widevine need Provisioning request.

" it is preferred to report the provisioning request as the first licensing request, and the app will send the HTTP POST for you. You can then send the real license request as an unsolicited license request once the provisioning response has been received"

Did you mean using SbDrmSessionUpdateRequestFunc to send a message to the page, let the page send a provisioning request to provisioning server and get the provisioning response? youtube page or qual page has this logic?

the Drm flow will be as follows , is that right? if not right,can give me the detail process ?

SbDrmCreateSystem -> 
SbDrmGenerateSessionUpdateRequest -> 
SbDrmSessionUpdateRequestFunc (with valid ticket and valid session_id to send provisioning request) -> 
SbDrmUpdateSession (update the provisioning response to CDM) -> 
SbDrmSessionUpdatedFunc (if this callback need?) -> 
SbDrmSessionUpdateRequestFunc (with invalid ticket and valid session_id to send real license request) ->
SbDrmUpdateSession (update the license response to CDM) -> 
SbDrmSessionUpdatedFunc (notify the license is success)

But When I call SbDrmSessionUpdateRequestFunc post the provisioning url and message to the page,the page don't use the url I post to it .It is a fixed value on the page at the Eme qual page.

the page is
https://yt-media-test.appspot.com/2018.html?test_type=encryptedmedia-test&command=off&disable_log=true&timestamp=1517552801994
run the first test case,the license server is a fixed value on the page at file
https://yt-media-test.appspot.com/js/lib/streams/mediaStreams-20180119121527.js

VideoSmallCenc: ['//yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/unit-tests/media/oops_cenc-20121114-142.mp4', 8017271, 242.71, {
          'mimeType': 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d4015"',
          'video_id': '03681262dc412c06',
          'playready_signature': '448279561E2755699618BE0A2402189D4A30B03B.0CD6A27286BD2DAF00577FFA21928665DCD320C2',
          'widevine_signature': '9C4BE99E6F517B51FED1F0B3B31966D3C5DAB9D6.6A1F30BB35F3A39A4CA814B731450D4CBD198FFD'}],
      VideoMultiKeyCenc: ['//yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/unit-tests/media/tears_h264_main_720p_1500.mp4', 105466539, 734.17, {
          'mimetype': 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d401f"',
          'pssh': util.createUint8ArrayFromJSArray([0, 0, 0, 68, 112, 115, 115, 104,
                                                    0, 0, 0, 0, 237, 239, 139, 169,
                                                    121, 214, 74, 206, 163, 200, 39, 220,
                                                    213, 29, 33, 237, 0, 0, 0, 36,
                                                    8, 1, 18, 1, 49, 26, 13, 119,
                                                    105, 100, 101, 118, 105, 110, 101, 95,
                                                    116, 101, 115, 116, 34, 10, 50, 48,
                                                    49, 53, 95, 116, 95, 49, 54, 107,
                                                    42, 2, 83, 68]),
          'license_server': 'https://proxy.staging.widevine.com/proxy'}],

Answer (score 0):

Using `SbDrmSessionUpdateRequestFunc` callback to request provisioning is legitimate and your flow looks correct.

That said, web apps may ignore the URL provided in the update request and use their own logic to perform provisioning. It seems that you expect yt-media-test to perform provisioning which it fails to do. To work around this issue, you can either 1) use youtube.com/tv (which is known to implement provisioning flow correctly) to provision the device before running EME tests, or 2) perform your own provisioning.

For issues with yt-media-test, please contact your YouTube account manager.